# How should I use the "parameters" parameter in the airflow. providers. snowflake. operators. snowflake. SnowflakeSqlApiOperator module

Tags: airflow-taskflow

I am using the SnowflakeSqlApiOperator module for airflow. providers. snowflake. operators. snowflake. I executed an SQL and used parameters.

But I received an error :SQL compilation error:\nsyntax error line 104 at position 16 unexpected '%'.\nsyntax error line 104 at position 28 unexpected 's'.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0U1gn.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
snowflake_task = SnowflakeSqlApiOperator(
    task_id="task_sqlapi",
    snowflake_conn_id  = 'snowflake_sqlapi__conn',
    sql ="select * from my_table where create_date = %(create_date)s",
    parameters = {'create_date' : '{{ ds_nodash }}'},
    )
```

This is the code I wrote

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).